# Повелительное наклонение и инфинитивы

Tags: глаголы, наклонение

Команды работы с файлом: открыть файл, сохранить файл, свернуть, свернуть в окно, закрыть, распечатать  - это инфинитивы в функции повелительного наклонения или просто инфинитивы? В английском языке они приводятся без частицы to. Это повелительное наклонение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Инфинитив может выражать любое наклонение, в том числе повелительное. https://goldrussian.ru/infinitiv-vroli-naklonenij.html

Инфинитив в значении повелительного наклонения подчеркивает **категоричность требования**, поэтому он используется **в командах** разного рода, например: Поднять паруса!

Соответственно, инфинитив используется и  **в командах при работе с файлом**: *открыть файл* – это значить *откройте файл*.

Answer (score 0):

Инфинитивы в функции повелительного наклонения – это, например, "Молчать!", "Не двигаться" и т.п. Немного не то, верно? Но по-английски это и правда, должно быть, повелительное наклонение: откройте, сохраните и т.д.